# ros openni and opencv

Tags: opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am making a human following robot using kinect. My plan is to use skeleton tracking to make the robot follow and using shirt color to identify the target.

I wonder how could i implement openni and opencv together?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209316/ros-openni-and-opencv/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In fact, I haven't use openni with kinect. I use freenect.
Maybe you can find necessary information in this website:http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_launch

If you want to run kinect. You just need to use

> `roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch`

Or sometimes , you might need to add authority for kinect's serial.

---

Originally posted by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) with karma: 224 on 2015-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-05-16**:
i cant find any paper that show reliable color detection.